# foreign phone stuck at Edge

Tags: 3g, gsm

I have Samsung galaxy j2 ( j200h/ds). Phone is supposed to connect to 3g but it never does. My current network is T-Mobile.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use [OpenSignal](http://opensignal.com/) to determine if your area actually does have 3G coverage from T-Mobile. I suspect that your area does not, and that is why you are not getting 3G service from T-Mobile. If you do get 3G coverage in your area, removing your SIM card and inserting it back into your phone will likely do the trick.